# Remove Trace Name in Plotly Hover while Keeping Standard Template

Tags: r, plotly

I produce a `plotly` waterfall chart like this:

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

data <- tibble(x = c("Sales", "Consulting", "Net revenue", "New Intermediate",
                     "Purchases", "Other expenses", "Profit before tax"), 
               measure = c("relative", "relative", "total", "absolute", "relative", 
                           "relative", "total"),
               text = c("+60", "+80", "", "", "-40", 
                        "-20", "Total"),
               y = c(60, 80, 0, 120, -40, -20, 0)) %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(x, x))


(fig <- data %>% 
    plot_ly() %>% 
    add_text(x = factor("Sales", levels = data$x),
           y = 80, text = "Some Text") %>%
    add_trace(type = "waterfall", measure = ~measure,
              x = ~x, textposition = "outside", y= ~y, text =~text,
              connector = list(line = list(color= "rgb(63, 63, 63)"))) %>%
    layout(title = "Profit and loss statement 2018",
           xaxis = list(title = ""),
           yaxis = list(title = ""),
           autosize = TRUE,
           showlegend = FALSE))
```

Because of the second `text` trace, the trace name is added by default to the hovertext:

[image: Hover Text shows Trace Name]

I know that I can remove it by supplying a custom `hovertemplate` where I add an empty `<extra></extra>` tag. My problem is that I quite like the default hovertemplate and I have no clue how I would reproduce it.

Thus, my question is which `hovertemplate` format string do I have to supply to get the exact hover as in the default case but without the trace name box?

This is what I tried, but it does not give my the nice triangles and shows too much text for non `relative` bars?

```r
data %>% 
  plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(type = "waterfall", measure = ~measure,
            x = ~x, textposition = "outside", y= ~y, text =~text,
            connector = list(line = list(color= "rgb(63, 63, 63)")),
            hovertemplate = "(%{x},%{y})<br>%{text}<br>%{delta}<br>Initial: %{initial}<extra></extra>") %>%
  add_text(x = factor("Sales", levels = data$x),
           y = 80, text = "Some Text") %>% 
  layout(title = "Profit and loss statement 2018",
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = ""),
         autosize = TRUE,
         showlegend = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want the legend, you can add `name = ""` in the `add_trace(type = "waterfall", ......)`.

Comment: OMG, was it really that easy? Must admit I doid not try this out, because my expectation was to see an empty white box. Perfect. But just for the record, would it be somehow possible to reconstruct the hover nevertheless?